# ArcGIS Camera animation

Tags: java, camera, arcgis, sceneview

I'm starting to learn ArcGIS API for Java (Runtime 100).
I need to do animation of SceneView() Camera.
According to API documentation, Camera can to have arguments such us roll and pitch. But when in reality, I can rotate just pitch of camera. When I set roll, nothing happened.
 For now I use very BAD solution: I add scale and rotate transformation for JavaFx Scene and rotate scene. It's bad because on rotation of 25-70 degree, I see gray background. How I can to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you include a source code example? You might get more help that way.

Comment: Code it just one line of : <code>camera = new com.esri.arcgisruntime.mapping.view.Camera(pos, dist, head, pitch, roll);</code>  And I'm can't to change "roll" parameter of camera. To solve it, I'm add additional camera on javafx scene, zoom it scene and after rotate camera of javafx scene .